# Grease Pencil Fill Tool Changes from 3.4 to 3.5

Tags: animation, 2d

I've been working with Blender for a few years now, mostly Grease Pencil. I absolutely love the tool and have never had a problem figuring out how to make things. But recently when I updated to Blender 3.5 the fill tool in grease pencil became almost unusable. I click inside the line work twice and it doesn't fill with the material. I know about gap closure etc. I can open the same file in 3.4 and everything with the fill tool works perfect. I just don't understand what changed. I've asked on a few youtube channels and on blenderartists.org. No answers so far. Does anyone have any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: The fill tool got quite changed [for v.3.4](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Reference/Release_Notes/3.4/Grease_Pencil) and quite frankly I haven't been able to make it fill like I did in v3.3 either. At best, I got new [contour lines of the wrong color](https://i.imgur.com/wmHDA5X.gif), using color attribute...

Comment: Looks like you need to click twice to get the fill performed.

Comment: Yes, first starts a modal to set the filling gap closure, second one does the actual filling. It's just not feeling right.

Comment: Thanks for your responses L0Lock and Josh. I actually didn't have a problem going from 3.3 to 3.4, I was still able to fill whatever outlines I needed. The problem for me started after I updated to 3.5. I am aware of different methods for closing gaps and I also know to click twice to fill. I'm still experiencing issues after many hours of troubleshooting. For now I will just go back to 3.4 where the tool works as expected. Thanks again for your input! Cheers!